# AWS Cloud Formation Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am new to cloud formation and I am building an elastic beanstalk environment. I get the above error when I run the template.  I have added the IAM roles giving full EC2 access to cloud formation

```
Resources:
  TestApp:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Properties: {}
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 53bb2af6-3a68-487a-8048-34f111147171

  EBE1RNK0:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref TestApp
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Node Sample Application
      EnvironmentName: NodejsEnvironment
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.0.1 running Node.js 12
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: InstanceType
          Value: t1.micro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the following:

```
Resources:
  TestApp:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Properties: {}
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 53bb2af6-3a68-487a-8048-34f111147171

  EBE1RNK0:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref TestApp
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Node Sample Application
      EnvironmentName: NodejsEnvironment
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.0.1 running Node.js 12
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: InstanceType
          Value: t1.micro
```

The environment name must have no space in it

Answer (score 1):

It should be (note `-`):

```
 OptionSettings:
   - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
     OptionName: InstanceType
     Value: t1.micro
```

Because is [OptionSettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-optionsettings) is:

> Type: List of OptionSetting

Comment: I added the note that you suggested but it gave me the following below error:              
Value Nodejs Environment at 'EnvironmentName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must contain only letters, digits, and the dash character and may not start or end with a dash (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 11e6b4d1-256a-4e8d-841e-07144341dd91)

Comment: @MB Name should not have spaces: NodejsEnvironment